# How to know if update successful or not with prisma?

Tags: mariadb, nestjs, prisma

updating a post comment with Prisma. As Prisma returns the updated comment, how to know if actually the update happened? Following is the code

```js
const updatedComment = await this.ps.comment.update({
      where: {
        id: commentId,
        userId: user.id,
      },
      data: {
        body,
      },
      include: {
        user: {
          select: {
            id: true,
            name: true,
          },
        },
      },
    }); // is the comment exists based on "where"? is it updated?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hey want do you think about using a condition statement. After the function you can check if the function returned an error or success.

For example:

```
if (updatedComment) {
  console.log('Comment updated successfully:', updatedComment);
} else {
  console.error('Comment not found or update failed.');
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Is it valid syntax? I think updatedComment is an struct